# Large Swing applet example

Tags: java, swing, applet

Does anybody know a good example of a large/complex applet based on Swing? I would like to compare its performance with JavaScript-based solutions (GWT, Vaadin, etc.).

Comment: Runescape at www.runescape.com

Comment: Thanks, but I need something more business-oriented, using standard Swing controls (buttons, lists, trees, etc.). There's no way to compare Runescape with GWT or Vaadin.

Comment: Hmm, not that large (nor business-oriented), but made (mainly) by me: http://www.fencing-game.de/. But I think if you are using Swing-like controls, normally the user speed is the bottleneck, not the GUI performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Swingset2`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#swingset2) is quite comprehensive. It can be run either as an [applet](/questions/tagged/applet) or a [java-web-start](/questions/tagged/java-web-start) application. Here's a link to the earlier [SwingSet2 applet](http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.5.0/demos/jfc/SwingSet2/SwingSet2.html).

Answer (score 2):

These are not overly complex but here's a couple you can consider

1. [An image processing application](http://student.dcu.ie/~oshafim2/GreenScreen/appletImageProcessing.html)
2. [A digital High Pass Filter simulator](http://student.dcu.ie/~oshafim2/DSP/HighPassFilterApplet.html)